# ConTeXt: Placing images with consistent height on grid

Tags: context, context-lmtx

While creating a layout for a brochure, I started to think about placing images on a page with a consistent height. I've got a bunch of 15x10cm images ready as PDF files.

In a DTP application I would place an image box with defined dimensions. And place the clipped image in there.

In ConTeXt I tried to get something similar. I used the `\clip` function, e.g. in order to get images with 10 x line height. Also following the approach shown on https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Example_photo_page_layout.

```
\define[2]\ClippedFigure{
    \startplacefigure[location=force,title={#1}]
    \clip[height=\dimexpr10\lineheight+\exheight\relax]{
        \externalfigure[{#2}][width=\textwidth]
    }
    \stopplacefigure
}
```

Is this the recommended approach to get images with consistent dimensions on a baseline grid?

Obviously scaling/cropping all images files first is possible in any case.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wiki, you have [`\startlinecorrection` and `\stoplinecorrection`](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startlinecorrection), but I'm not sure whether or not the outcome is what you'd expect from it. See the example below:

```tex
\setuplayout
  [grid=on]
% This loads cow.pdf for purposes of testing
% \setupexternalfigures[location={local,global,default}]
% And this show the grid...
% \showgrid
\starttexdefinition ClippedFigure #1 #2
  \startplacefigure[location={force},title={#1}]
  \startlinecorrection
  % \exheight adds one more line
  \clip[height=\dimexpr10\lineheight\relax]{
    \externalfigure[#2][width=\textwidth]
  }
  \stoplinecorrection
  \stopplacefigure
\stoptexdefinition
\starttext
\ClippedFigure{Cow}{cow.pdf}
\stoptext
```

[image]